# Setting out.seq parameter for barabasi scale free models in r

Tags: r, igraph

I have an undirected graph. I want to create barabasi's scale free network model for this graph. I want to to pass out.dist arguments to set number of edges in network. But if i will pass my vector of degrees in the out.seq then the sum of the degree in the undirected network would be the double of from the number of edges. So how to set this parameter when my network is undirected.My r script is

```
library(igraph)
gtest <- graph.formula(A:B - A:B, X:Z - X:Y - X:B, C:Z , C:X ,A:C - A:C)
plot(gtest)
g_scale_ex <- ba.game(6 , out.dist = degree(gtest) , directed = F)
```

g_scale_ex woul be having 14 number of edges where as it should be 7.

Comment: Struggling for these please help.

Comment: If you look at `?ba.game()`, it says that the first parameter passed in is the number of vertices instead of edges, which is the case for your result.

Comment: @Psidom Sorry that was my typing mistake. Then also i will get number of edges as 13 instead of 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want one of two things. If you want the exact degree sequence then you're better of with (using new igraph function names):

```
g <- sample_degseq(degree(gtest))
gsize(g) # Number of edges
# 7
gorder(g) # Number of nodes
# 6
```

If you want a Barabasi preferential attachment network then it's a little harder specifying the precise number of edges. I answered a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37178286/generate-random-network-models-with-specified-number-of-edges-in-r/37272359) where there's a little function to generate the right `out.seq` argument.

```
genOutSeq <- function(n, m) {
  n <- n-1 # Shift it along
  rem <- m %% n
  c(0, rep(m%/%n + 1, rem), rep(m%/%n, n - rem))
}

set.seed(11)
g <- sample_pa(gorder(gtest), power = 1,
               out.seq = genOutSeq(gorder(gtest), gsize(gtest)),
               algorithm = "psumtree-multiple", directed = FALSE)
```

This will create the right number of edges but some are multiple. The default algorithm won't create multi-edges but might not create exactly the right number.

```
set.seed(11)
g <- sample_pa(gorder(gtest), power = 1,
               out.seq = genOutSeq(gorder(gtest), gsize(gtest)),
               directed = FALSE)
gsize(g)
# 6
```

As far as I know there's no way to keep adding edges until you hit your quoter. In the answer I linked to I just add a few random edges because it's usually not that many so long as your graph isn't too dense.

Comment: thanks for the answer. The sample_degseq function is nothing but the generalized random network model with the given degree distribution. That is the configuration model. But if we provide degree distribution of our random network same as the degree distribution of our actual network then there would be no means of comparing random network models with real life models.

Comment: OK, by sending in the degree to out.seq it looked like you wanted that degree distribution. I offered both as it wasn't clear which you wanted. So the second one is probably what you need.

Comment: Did you spot the sample_pa option underneath?

Comment: Can you please tell What does this genOutSeq actually do.? I am not getting it.

Comment: Yeah it's a bit ugly with all the mods and divs. The `out.seq` argument is the number of new edges to add each iteration of the BA model. So each step a node is added and it has a certain number of edges that it uses to connect into the network. the `genOutSeq` function creates a vector of the number of edges to introduce at each step. If you do `sum(genOutSeq(n, m))` it should be `m` and it spreads them out evenly. So if there were 5 nodes and 7 edges it would be 0,2,2,2,1

Comment: But if we add out.seq parameter like this then the degree distribution will not follow scale free nature.

Comment: The scale free comes from the preferential attachment not out.seq part. Of course we can test it with a big enough graph.